# Serializing a django User model which is inherited as OnetoOnefield in another model gives "TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable"

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-users

I am trying to make an Instagram API clone using Django rest framework.
I have created an account module that has two fields - user,AccountType. user is a OnetoOneField with the Django User model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

User=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PUBLIC='pub'
    PRIVATE='pvt'
    Account_choices=[
        (PUBLIC,'Public'),
        (PRIVATE,'Private')
    ]
    AccountType=models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=Account_choices,default=PUBLIC)
```

I created a serializer for this model.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Account

class AccountCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields=['user','AccountType']
```

In the views I received data from a client and used the data to create a User object and then use this user object to create an Account object. But when I try to serialize the data and check if it is_valid it reurns False. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    email = request.data['email']
    

    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    data={
        'user':user,
        'AccountType':'pub'
    }
    serializer = AccountCreateSerializer(data=data)
    return Response(data)
```

I tried giving the serializer input as a dictionary and even the username as just a string.

githubLink: https://github.com/henselwilson/Instafam.git

Comment: You alredy created an account for that user: a `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` that is unique, so you can not create a second account for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You alredy created an account for that user: a `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` that is unique, so you can not create a second account for that user.

You thus let the serializer do the work:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    email = request.data['email']

    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    # do not create an Account
    data = {'user': user, 'AccountType': 'pub'}
    serializer = AccountCreateSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not creating another account.
user = User.objects.create_user(...) 
only creates a User but not an account. I am able to create an account with
account = Account.objects.create(user=user, AccountType='pub')
It is just that when I pass user object as a element in the dictionary and use it to serialize the is_valid function gives False. 
I am trying to get serializer to give me True, so that I can validate my data properly and then save.

Comment: @HENSELWILSONGOVEAS: you are, you create an `Account` with `Account.objects.create()`, and then the serializer is asked to validate if it can create an account, so a second one.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes I have created an account and it is successful. But evenif I remove that line of code, serializaer still returns False
Let me remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: @HENSELWILSONGOVEAS: what does `serializer.errors` prints?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have edited the issue. I would also like to say that I tried to add account through a webpage through a form. I used a form.is_valid function to validate it and that worked fine. I was able to save the form. I even checked the data type of 'user' returned by the form
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
It is the same as the user variable which i pass to the serializer